# Constantly sending data with ajax in chrome extension

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

is it possible to post data from google chrome extension to another page, for example every minute? Someone opens chrome and then every minute will be information send to my page.. Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is very possible. A short simple example:

**background page**

```
//These make sure that our function is run every time the browser is opened.
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  initialize();
});
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
  initialize();
});
function initialize(){
  setInterval(function(){sendData()},60000);
}
function sendData(){
  //Assuming data contains the data you want to post and url is the url
  $.post(url,data);
}
```

**Manifest.json**

We need to request host permissions for where we are posting. Something along the lines of "http://www.example.com/postHere.php". See [Match Patterns](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html) for more.

```
{
  "name": "Chrome post test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "A test for posting",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "http://www.example.com/postHere.php"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-1.8.3.min.js","background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `setInterval()`. You should wrap your logic in it in your background page. And don't forget to add `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"` in your manifest.json if you are excute a string. For more you may want to browse [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html).